# hide some div using javascript in wkwebview

Tags: javascript, html, wkwebview

I'm using wkwebview for all URL. Now you can see in my image I want to hide some specific `div` (like it displaying all platform in bottom). So how can I hide all the platform using specific javascript.
[image]

```
let js = "$('#platforms').children().hide();"
        self.webView?.evaluateJavaScript(js) { (_, error) in
            print(error)
        }
```

I've already tried some javascript code but it didn't work in wkwebview, so please give me proper guidance.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: hello habed,
nope i did'nt get solution yet.

but i think with the help of WKWebView we can done this type of things.

Thanks.